# How do I attach the specific app to Selendroid test suite?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver

How does one attach a specific app which is to be tested to `Selendroid`?
I've seen the example with the test app which is displayed virtually everywhere, but well, where do I have to place that apk under test?
I tried to use the id of the app like this:

```
    SelendroidConfiguration config = new SelendroidConfiguration();
    config.addSupportedApp("io.selendroid.testapp:0.17.0");

    SelendroidLauncher selendroidServer = new SelendroidLauncher(config);
    selendroidServer.launchSelendroid();


    DesiredCapabilities caps = io.selendroid.common.SelendroidCapabilities.android();
    SelendroidCapabilities cap = new SelendroidCapabilities("io.selendroid.testapp:0.17.0");
```

But I keep receiving errors: `SessionNotCreatedException`. What is causing this?
How do I attach a specific app to the `Java` project with the tests?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is caused by not giving the correct path to your apk.

**Here you should give the path to the apk, but you are giving it the package name of the app**

```
   config.addSupportedApp("io.selendroid.testapp:0.17.0");
```

**The fix would be then**

```
  config.addSupportedApp("C:/Users/Madis/Documents/selendroid.apk");
```